# What is the unit and dimension of a matrix operator in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, dimensional-analysis, si-units, x-ray-crystallography

Let us consider the higher order Born approximation that explains multiple scattering. The well-known Born expansion leads to the expression for transition "matrix" or "T-matrix" which represents multiple scattering.
It is given as
$$\hat{T}=\hat{V}+\hat{V}G_0\hat{V}+\hat{V}G_0\hat{V}G_0\hat{V}+ \cdots.$$

Here $V$ is the potential and $G_0$ is the Green's function. My question is what is the unit of $T$? If you consider the first term in the RHS then the unit of $T$ should be same as that of $V$. But if you look at subsequent terms in the RHS of the expression then the equation seems dimensionally incorrect. This looks puzzling to me. What is the rule to preserve the units and dimensions of the equations involving matrix operators in quantum mechanics?

Comment: I might be misremembering (hence not an answer) but aren't there hidden factors of $\hbar$ that are being set to $1$ in this expansion? At any rate, dimensions in QM work as normal, we're just in some convention where $GV$ is dimensionless.

Comment: It is about electric field in the potential of the scatterer. The perturbation term V has dimension of charge/area from its expression [V=4*pi*r_0*(charge/volume)] and the Green's function G_0 has dimension of 1/r from its expression. The differential equation is (del^2+k^2)E(x)=V(x)E(x)

Comment: @jacob1729 It is a lot easier to understand what's going on if we recognize that e.g. $H$ means $H/\hbar$ rather than saying "$\hbar$ is equal to 1".

Answer (score 6):

In scattering theory, $\hat V$ is a potential and has units of energy, while the Green's function is
$$
\hat G_0=(E-\hat H_0+i0^+)^{-1}
$$
has units of the inverse of an energy.

Therefore, there isn't any problem of dimensional analysis in the definition of the T-matrix.